# How to filter function parameters

Tags: php, mysql, function

What is a proper way to filter parameters passed in functions? The goal is to make the function secure, especially when working with a database.

Example:

```
function user_profile($user_id)
{
   //get user's profile data
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id";
}
```

`$user_id` is a URI segment.

Other general examples are welcomed.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string see here:http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: ADO would be the _most_ secure. However, I'm questioning using a URI segment as a unique key--interesting.

Comment: Brad would you please explain it more?I have eager to know abt it

Comment: The URI segment is used to retrieve data from a respective user. when browsing users on a site. There's no other way to pass the user id as far as i know, other than through the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape strings, use the same method you'd use outside the function:

```
$user_id= mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);
```

If you're expecting the value to be, for example, an integer and would like to return error from the function if it isn't, you can do something like:

```
if (!is_int($user_id)) {
  return FALSE;
}
else // do you query
```

Or if you expect it to match some specific pattern, do so with `preg_match()`:

```
// For example, $user_id should be 4 letters and 4 numbers
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}$/", $user_id)) {
   return FALSE;
}
else // do you query
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways.  The OLD way is to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  **However**, many people nowadays complain bitterly about this, and say the proper way is to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

Create a filter class to handle all your filtering. Before you pass the variable into the function as a parameter, pass it through the filter class first. Or run the parameter through the filter class in the first line of your function.

So essentially, you're creating an abstract layer that 'filters'.

So the kind of filtering you're wanting to do in your scenario is to filter against sql injection/code injections.

So create a wrapper with this filter class around the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function.

The idea is to create an extensible filter class that can be used anywhere else in your application that is conceptually high level enough to handle all future needs.

```
final class Filter
{
    static public function sqlInjections($some_parameter)
    {
        // my code to prevent injections by filtering $some_parameter
        return mysql_real_escape_string($some_paramters);
    }

    static public function badWords()
    {
        // code in the future that can be added to filter bad words
    }
}
```

call it like so `$filtered_parameter = Filter::sqlInjections($some_paramter);`

Comment: Thanks for the sample code! A filter class is a great idea. Why are the functions `static` ? I had in mind to make them private.

Comment: @CyberJunkie no, don't make them private otherwise you won't be able to call on them. They're static so you don't have to instantiate the class and use an object to use the method (less lines of code)

Answer (score 1):

**If your `user_id` field is a string** in your database, then, you'll use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), or [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://fr.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string), or [`PDO::quote()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) -- **depending on the API you're working with** :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '" 
              . mysql_real_escape_string($user_id) . "'";
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '" 
              . mysqli_real_escape_string($user_id) . "'";
```

or, with PDO -- provided that `$db` is a `PDO` object :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '" 
              . $db->quote($user_id) . "'";
```

But, **if it's an integer**, you should make sure that the value passed to it is indeed an integer -- which is generally done using [**`intval()`**][4] :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = " 
              . intval($user_id);
```

*<sub>Edit: I just realized you said it's an URL segment -- so, not an integer. I don't delete this idea, though: it might help someone else who would read this answer.</sub>*

Another solution would be to not build a query containing that value -- and use **prepared statements**.

See :

- For mysqli : [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
- And with PDO : [`PDO::prepare()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: The URL segment is numeric so should actually be an integer when querying. The answer is valid for me.

Comment: Well, glad I didn't edit-out that part of my answer, then :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($user_id) . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two or Three complementary ways to prevent SQL injection:

- The escape functions commented above.
- Query the other way around:

  function user_profile($user_id)
  {
     //get user's profile data
     $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE {$user_id} = `user_id`";
  }
- User prepare and execute functions/methods if your database engine allow it
  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
  http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php